# Call a post method from a controller method (using url pattern)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following form

```
<form name="fbForm" action="myIp/projectName/ControllerName/method" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="email">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="dob">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="sex">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

My Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String email,@RequestParam String dob,@RequestParam String sex) {

    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println(email);
    System.out.println(dob);
    System.out.println(sex);

    return "test";
}
```

If i click on the submit button in the form it works fine and prints desired output.
Now what i am trying to do is call this signup method from another controller method

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/anotherMethod" )
public void callSignup() {

    // code to call signup using url pattern (ControllerName/method) method from here with (username,email,dob,sex)

}
```

is it possible?? How can i do this?

Please answer with example code

Sorry I could not ask the question properly. I don't need to call the method by method name but by the url pattern

so the call should be made to `ControllerName/method` not `signup()`

Comment: Did you even try calling it?

Comment: Example code: `String s = signup(username, email, dob, sex);`.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to call one controller from another.

You should do one of two things: 1) Call the service method that the second controller's method calls (assuming that there is one)
2) Send the browser a redirect HTTP response by using `return "redirect:/anotherMethod"` or whatever you need there

Comment: there is a second controller. could you write some sample code

Comment: Just do return "redirect:${path-you-would-use-to-hit-the-method-from-a-browser}"

Comment: hi this just goes to the redirect page but i also need the information with it (username,sex.....etc) as post (so that i can catch it with @Request param). sending it via path variable wont work for me

Comment: If it were not a POST but a GET method you could append the information you need as URL params and they would be picked up by @RequestParam. I don't know what else to tell you because I don't know the details of your implementation

Comment: Get is not an option for me here because i am sending password.

Answer (score 0):

While this works (it's just a Java method, after all), I would advise against it. Calling a public entry point with defined semantics from another public entry point with different semantics violates the principle of least astonishment. Instead, the logic you need should be extracted to a private method that is called from both entry points.

Comment: There's no architectural problem with doing this, and I do it routinely when writing HTML controllers exposing the same functionality as JSON REST. The "entry point" you're talking about is only the mapping metadata that connects a URL to the controller method, and the method itself is a perfectly legitimate service method for another frontend component.

Comment: @chrylis the scenario you mention is more valid than that of the OP, but I'd still prefer to extract the functionality to a dedicated method. It's a tradeoff btw loc and separation of concerns, I guess, and for me the latter wins.

Comment: Suppose it depends greatly on what code is actually in the controller methods; I generally try to make mine fairly thin wrappers around service objects. But the recommendation of private methods implies a very different decomposition pattern from putting business logic in a service bean.